# How to associate an arxiv paper on Google Scholar with the rest of my account?

Tags: arxiv, google-scholar

So I'm just beginning my PhD and I want to associate this paper that I put on arxiv with my Google scholar profile, but I don't see how to do this.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

ArXiv papers take a few days to get indexed by Google scholar. It should show up eventually. The procedure to add it your profile is no different than with any other paper from any other database.

Comment: Could you define "eventually"? I also don't see an obvious way to add an arXiv paper manually such that it looks like other arXiv papers on Google Scholar

Comment: @Psi If you add arxiv paper manually, it still won't show up on google scholar search. You have to wait for its appearing in scholar automatically.

Comment: And is there a quantifiable number to how long the wait is?