# Adding Presentation and data in Google Scholar

Tags: phd

I would like to ask whether it is possible to add a presentation and data in google scholar. I am asking that because during conference there were people interested in using my data and presentation, however, these data hasn't been published yet.

So, my question is: could the presentations and data be cited as published articles or not?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Are you suggesting to add your conference talks as "publications" in Google Scholar? Do you want to know how to add a link to slides and other material next to a listed publication? Or something else entirely? "Counted" by whom? Could you please check your grammar and add a "real" question with a question mark at the end? This sounds like it could be a good question for this site, but it needs work.

Comment: Sorry for poor English, I have edited my question. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to *publish* content in a way that shows from your Google Scholar profile. Luckily there are many ways of getting that done nowadays, and quickly.

I suggest you upload and curate all of your datasets and raw annotations to a stable, reputable data repository, such as Figshare, Zenodo, or Mendeley Datasets. As suggested in another answer here.

Once you have your dataset ready and understandable, I recommend you write a manuscript about it for publication. You can easily **publish** a draft version on a preprint server, such as arXiv.org and/or related websites. There you're *done*: as soon as indexed Google Scholar should be able to find your manuscript. From this point the situation is akin to [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79801/how-to-associate-an-arxiv-paper-on-google-scholar-with-the-rest-of-my-account) and related questions, in case of any doubts.

Welcome to Open Science. As some peers say, ["open science is merely science done right"](https://zenodo.org/record/1285575#.W7tRPsaZOiI).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

[Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html) usually (not always) just crawl the contents which are organized like a research article. If it's just a presentation (e.g. powerpoint, LaTeX beamer, poster, etc.) you could upload it in [F1000Research](https://f1000research.com/) or [Figshare](http://figshare.com) which could give you a DOI and will be fully citable. But it does not guarantee that it will be indexed by Google Scholar. Also I like [Figshare](http://figshare.com) cause you could share your data with presentation/paper/pre-print under Common Creative license (it's not the only license available in the [Figshare](http://figshare.com)).