# How much time Google Scholar take (generally) to index an arXiv document?

Tags: arxiv, google-scholar

recently I have arXived a manuscript of mine but it is not indexed by google scholar and around 64 hrs have passed. Is there anything else I have to do in order to get indexed by google scholar or will google scholar index the manuscript automatically?

P.S. arXived was done successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It usually takes a few days [according to this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79801/how-to-associate-an-arxiv-paper-on-google-scholar-with-the-rest-of-my-account), which is in-line with my experience (I don't really monitor it though). In some cases, I think it can take a couple of weeks for Crossref which may give an idea of how long it could take for Google Scholar.

If you want to, you can [manually add the article](https://answers.library.westernsydney.edu.au/faq/196423) to your Google Scholar profile. However, I'm not sure how quickly that affects indexing.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the detailed answer.